React-native app syntax errors in library code while bundling
I'm encountering a perplexing issue while working on my React Native app.

I have a production version already deployed, and I'm currently making some UI modifications.
Suddenly, without any apparent reason (at least not due to my code
modifications), I'm encountering syntax errors in the code of certain
Node libraries like react-native-async-storage, native-base, among
others.
These errors occur during bundling, and they're persistent, appearing
in at least 90% of bundling attempts in my Expo dev environment.

What I have Tried:

I've tried the basic troubleshooting steps such as uninstalling and reinstalling Node packages and CocoaPods, but the errors persist.

What's more puzzling is that the errors seem to jump between
different libraries in each bundling attempt, always manifesting as
syntax errors within the library code.

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I've also upgraded all packages, ensuring compatibility among them. However, the problem persists.


I've attached my package.json, podfile, app.json, and screenshots of the errors encountered for reference.
Is anyone else experiencing similar issues or has encountered them in the past? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
errors:
SyntaxError: /.../node_modules/native-base/src/129%6/index ts: Unexpected token, expected """
27 | export interface /CustomTheme f
29 | export interface ITheme extends /CustomTheme, Omit<Theme, keyof (CustomTheme> (
30 |
31 | export {theme, tools as themeTools };
321 RCTFatal
_28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
_QUEULOOP IS SERVICING-THE MAIN DISPATCH

> SyntaxError:
> /.../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/src/
> AsyncStorage.native.ts: Missing semicolon. (270:48) 2681 }; 269 |
> const promiseResult = new Promise<readonly KeyValuePair I]>( 2711
> (resolve, reject) => { 272 | 273| getrequest resolve resolve: RCTFatal

package.json:
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@alessiocancian/react-native-actionsheet": "^3.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.5",
    "@expo/config": "~9.0.0",
    "@expo/metro-config": "~0.18.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.5.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.1.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.1.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.1",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.4.1",
    "expo-asset": "~10.0.6",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.5.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.13",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.12.10",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.1",
    "expo-random": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "metro-config": "~0.80.4",
    "metro-resolver": "0.79.0",
    "metro-source-map": "0.80.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-accordion": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-native": "^6.23.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.5",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "metro": "~0.80.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "...",
    "slug": "...",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "scheme": "siva24",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "jsEngine": "hermes",
      "bundleIdentifier": "...",
      "buildNumber": "20",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Consenti l'utilizzo all'uso della fotocamera per l'invio di foto inerenti ai veicoli consultati",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Permettere l'uso della fototeca per inviare le foto dei veicoli consultati.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Abilita l'uso della localizzazione per ottenere i veicoli vicini.",
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [
          {
            "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
              "..."
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "..."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "...",
      "versionCode": 8,
      "jsEngine": "hermes",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "NOTIFICATIONS",
        "CAMERA",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ],
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    },
    "overrides": {
      "metro": "0.76.4",
      "metro-resolver": "0.76.4"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-asset",
      "expo-font"
    ]
  }
}

babel.config.js:
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'];
  const plugins = ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', '@babel/plugin-syntax-flow'];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};

metro.config.js:
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;

I expected

Uninstalling and reinstalling the packages would resolve any issues related to corrupt or missing dependencies.
Upgrading dependencies would address any version conflicts between
packages.
Identify any discrepancies between my
code and the dependency versions that might cause compatibility
problems.

